# Grails datasource - idle connections in production

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails

I am developing a grails application which uses PostgreSQL as database. When performing db actions in development mode on local machine (windows) everything is working as it should (pool, idle connection cleaning etc..)

The problem occurs when I build a war file and deploy it on tomcat (linux machine). As soon as I start using application, the database connections are not cleaned from db and they stay in idle state.

When I check connections on db and their queries I see hundred of "COMMIT" and "COMMIT TRANSACTION" queries which are in idle state and dont get cleaned.

Also all the datasource configurations are not being applied on remote machine.

Any help would be welcome since I tried lots of options but the issue still remains.

**Update 1:**

Grails version: 2.2.3
Hibernate version: 2.2.3

```
dataSource {        
    pooled = true
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
    hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache=true
    cache.use_query_cache=true
    cache.provider_class='net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
environments { 
development {
    dataSource {
        logSql=false
        dbCreate = "none"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
        driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
        properties {
            initialSize = 3
            maxActive = 100
            maxIdle = 50
            minIdle = 10
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=2000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=false
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            removeAbandoned = true
            removeAbandonedTimeout = 54
        }
    }
} 
}
```

After some testing I found out that these settings are not being applied at all. No matter if environment is development or production. In development environment I can see with pg_stat_activity query that connections are being rotated at 50 (when number of connections reaches 50 it does the cleanup) while in production the connections are not being cleaned up at all and when they reach max_connections value then I get "Too many clients" error.

With pg_stat_activity check I can see most of queries are:

- COMIT
- COMIT TRANSACTION
- SET extra_float_digits = 3

**Update 2:**

At last I figured out that issue is related to the delayed datasource workaround http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=312 .

I did not add DelayedSessionFactoryBean to my code and that is why hibernate did not set configuration on the fly.

Comment: "check connections on db and their queries". How? If you mean `pg_stat_activity`, it shows the last command run, so if it's shown as idle that just means the last thing it did was a `COMMIT`.

Comment: You need to post your Hibernate configuration (e.g. DataSource, transaction management) so I can figure out your issue.